# Render output only when conditionalPanel conditions satisfied

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am writing a Shiny app that will be deployed across various users with screen resolutions ranging from 720p to 1080p. The application will be deployed on the web.

My page has a simple sidebar and a main content area. In order to adjust the width of the sidebar (to contain all the contents without any scrolling), I used two `conditionalPanels` in my UI.r, which render the appropriate 1080p or 720p UIs by evaluating `"screen.width > 1600"` or `"screen.width < 1600"`.

This works fine, and the appropriate UIs are rendered as required.

However, after profiling the application, I realized that while the appropriate UI panels were indeed displayed, my server code was rendering both the high resolution and low resolution outputs, even though only one is being displayed at any given time.

Is there any way to disable the output that is not being displayed? I was looking into using global variables, since the screen width is never going to change during a session, but I was having trouble with shinyjs and evaluating the `"screen.width"` expression--it seems to return `NULL` anywhere but inside a `conditionalPanel`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a minimal reproducible example, providing a solution is difficult. But `req` or `validate` and `need` might be what you want.

`req` is used to check values exist prior to execution: [req documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html).

`validate` and `need` can be used together in a very similar way: [validate documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.0/validate.html).

For example, you might try:

```
output$my_1080_plot = renderPlot(
    validate(need(screen.width > 1600, message = FALSE))
    # other commands to make plot
)
```

If the logical condition is not met then evaluation ceases and the other command are not run.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need. I don't think I ever would have found those functions myself. Thanks.